# Missing Script generated by Webpack(development) on first page load

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

the first time i load the `login` page the `login.js` script doesn't load , only the `shared.js` bundle loads (which has bootstrap js/css and toastr css), if i refresh the page everything loads without problems and after that there are no problems.

Pretty much every time i restart my local server i need refresh the login page to be able to login

my webpack config is as follows

```
export default {
  entry: {
    shared: [
      './src/3rdparty/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js',
      './src/3rdparty/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css',
      './src/3rdparty/toastr/toastr.min.css',
      ],
    login : {
      import: './src/pages/login.js',
      filename: 'main/login.js',
      dependOn: 'shared',
      chunkLoading: false,
    }
  },
  output:{
    path: fileURLToPath(new URL('public',import.meta.url)),
    clean:true,
  },
  resolve:{
    extensions: ['.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ],
  mode: 'development'
}
```

The project has been build using `Node 16.17` / `Expressjs 4`

It works without problems if i change the mode to `production`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to write in case i encounter the same issue again:

after adding the `compression` library i cannot replicate the issue

another issue that i had was that when i was returning messages from the server with the status 400, it would return a invalid string Ex:

```
{ok:true, description:"username invalid"
```

always missing the closing bracket `}`

this issue has also been resolved by using `compression` middleware